# Calling GAP's StructureDescription from SAGE

Tags: computational-mathematics, gap, sagemath

Given a sage group object $G$, I want to obtain its structure description using GAP, as follows:

```
sage:  gap.StructureDescription(G)
```

The command works fine in sagenb.org, but on my local installation I get an error message like this:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

/opt/sage-5.3-linux-64bit-ubuntu_12.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/interface.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
...
RuntimeError: Gap produced error output
Error, the Small Groups identification is required but not installed

   executing StructureDescription($sage1);
```

I was thinking that perhaps I need to install the small groups library.  I'm using ubuntu, and in the /usr/local/bin directory I typed:

```
> sudo sage  -i database_gap-4.4.9
```

But I still get the error for the `gap.StructureDescription(G)` command.  How do I get this command to work?

Comment: http://www.sagemath.org/packages/optional/ lists `database_gap-4.6.4.spkg`, while you've tried to install `database_gap-4.4.9` - maybe it's a simple version mismatch?

Comment: I got an error when I tried to install this package.

Comment: It may be packages archive ahead of the version of the core system. Could you try to call `optional_packages` as in my answer to see which version to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of installing additional GAP components in just installed Sage 5.13 (version numbers may differ in your particular installation, if you have an older version of Sage):

1) Call `optional_packages` and find names or relevant things (which will hopefully have version numbers matching the core GAP system):

```
sage: optional_packages()
   ...
  'database_gap-4.6.4',
  ...
  'gap_packages-4.6.4.p1',
  ...
```

2) Call `install_package` for those components in which you are interested:

```
sage: install_package('database_gap-4.6.4')

... lots of output ...

sage: install_package('gap_packages-4.6.4.p1')

... lots of output ...
```

3) Check how the GAP welcome screen looks like:

```
sage: gap_console();
 ┌───────┐   GAP, Version 4.6.4 of 04-May-2013 (free software, GPL)
 │  GAP  │   http://www.gap-system.org
 └───────┘   Architecture: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0-gcc-default64
 Libs used:  gmp, readline
 Loading the library and packages ...
 Components: trans 1.0, prim 2.1, small* 1.0, id* 1.0
 Packages:   Alnuth 3.0.0, AutPGrp 1.5, CTblLib 1.2.2, FactInt 1.5.3, 
             GAPDoc 1.5.1, LAGUNA 3.6.3, Polycyclic 2.11, TomLib 1.2.2
 Try '?help' for help. See also  '?copyright' and  '?authors'
gap>
```

In particular, you may be interested in lines

```
 Components: trans 1.0, prim 2.1, small* 1.0, id* 1.0
```

where `small* 1.0, id* 1.0` stands for the Small Groups Library, and

```
 Packages:   Alnuth 3.0.0, AutPGrp 1.5, CTblLib 1.2.2, FactInt 1.5.3, 
             GAPDoc 1.5.1, LAGUNA 3.6.3, Polycyclic 2.11, TomLib 1.2.2
```

which list some packages that are loaded by default.

4) Now `gap.StructureDescription` works:

```
sage: G = PermutationGroup(['(1,2,3)(4,5)', '(3,4)'])
sage: gap.StructureDescription(G)
S5
```

In addition, it may be useful to check ["Can non-isomorphic groups have equal structure descriptions?"](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.12) from the GAP F.A.Q.

**Disclaimers**

- [The latest version of GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/index.html) available for standalone installation may be newer than the one available with Sage
- Not all packages that are redistributed with GAP are available in `gap-packages-...` component installed as above (there are 114 packages redistributed with GAP 4.7.2), but there is a way to install additional packages manually. On the other hand, Sage includes the braid package, which has been superseded by [MapClass](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/~jamesa/mapclass/) which is now an accepted package redistributed with GAP.

Comment: Please use @username mechanism to ping me, otherwise I've discovered your comments below only by revisiting this page. Have you finally managed to get it work?

Comment: $+1$ I am learning more and more. :-)

Comment: Currently (April 2020), this recipe fails : "NameError: name 'install_package' is not defined".

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above, also on ubuntu, and got the same error. I believe it is for exactly the reason stated, that the SmallGroups library is needed. From this link http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals//doc/ref/chap76.html#X7B6CD527825945CD it appears that not only do you need to install the package, you most likely need to load it with gap.LoadPackage(name) before you can use it.

Comment: No, the Small Groups Library does not have to be loaded with `LoadPackage`. If available, it loads automatically when GAP is started.

Comment: Does the Small Groups Library load automatically when SAGE is started?  I need to invoke the gap.StructureDescription(G) command from the SAGE console.

Comment: @AG.: yes, it does. Try to execute `gap_console();` in Sage to see the GAP banner and various information. Loom for the line like `Components: trans 1.0, prim 2.1, small* 1.0, id* 1.0` - can you see it?

Comment: gap_console() does launch GAP successfully, but note that the group object $G$ does not get loaded into this GAP session.  I need to stay within the SAGE console I think.

Comment: hmm, so do you see `small* 1.0, id* 1.0` in the GAP startup screen,  but `gap.StructureDescription(G)` still doesn't work?

Comment: gap_console() gives only the following one line: ``GAP4, Version: 4.4.12 of 17-Dec-2008, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc''

Comment: That's 5-years old GAP, so likely not the most recent Sage release. Is there `database_gap-4.4.12` available?

Comment: P.S. http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/4.4.12.html provides archives for GAP 4.4.12 - if you will find where GAP 4.4.12 sits inside your Sage installation, you may figure out what and how to drop there to add Small Groups Library. However, YMMV. There were fixes in `StructureDecription` in subsequent GAP releases, and I'd very much advise to switch to the latest version.

Comment: I installed the latest versions of SAGE and GAP and they work file now.

Comment: @AG.: great, thanks for confirming this.